# Updating data in multiple places without reloading the page

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How to update data in multiple places without reloading the page in Vue.js?

This is my example. 
[image]
When I add a new application, a new reminder is created. How to use this data in different places on the page?

**Important**: all elements are in different components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) or a [global event bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) depending on the complexity of your application.

If your application is starting to become more enriched with Vue components that need to communicate beyond simple child/parent and parent/child communications, then Vuex should be a good fit.

I am not going to go into depth about the technicalities because that information can be found in the documentation. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Stephan-v. I heard about Vuex, but didn't know whether I should apply it in this case.